# Sonar test coverage does not include indirect classes

Tags: java, sonarqube

If I have the below classes (A and B) which are each in a separate module and I create a test for `A.doSomething()`, Sonar will complain about **0%** coverage on `B.doSomething()` although it is being testing indirectly in `TestA`.
Using **Ecclema** coverage plugin for eclipse, I can `see B.doSomething()` is considered as covered.

Is there a reason for why Sonar acts this way? Is there a way to change the behavior of Sonar's code test coverage to include indirectly tested classes?

```
class A {
    boolean doSomething() {
        return new B().doSomething();
    }
}

class B {
    boolean doSomething() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, except if your classes are in separate modules/sub-projects (there is currently no cross-module coverage computation).

Comment: @Mithfindel Yes, they are each in a separate module. There is no possible workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you want. This is a matter of how you configure JaCoCo so it has little to do with SonarQube.
For example in SonarQube Eclipse project we need that since unit tests are in a separate module.

So we have configured JaCoCo to use the same dump file for all modules (by default JaCoCo Maven plugin will use one separate dump per module):
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse/blob/master/pom.xml#L373

And then we configured SonarQube JaCoCo plugin to use the same report:
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse/blob/master/pom.xml#L357

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question and Mithfindel's answer seems more correct. Actually I have one test method which only tests `class A`. In this test which is in `project A`, the method from `class B` which is in `project B` gets called. So it isn't really about aggregating reports because there is only one test. It is about Jacoco unable to detect coverage of indirectly called methods/classes which is the case of `class B`.

Comment: This *is* about aggregating reports, and then configuring SQ analysis to use the same report for all modules. With default behavior, executing tests on moduleA will produce a coverage report in moduleA/target that contains coverage of classA and classB. When SQ analysis is executed, when analysing moduleA it read moduleA/target/jacoco.exec to set coverage on classA. When analysing moduleB, it looks for coverage report in moduleB/target and don't find one so no coverage is reported on classB. If you configure analysis to use moduleA/target/jacoco.exec for all modules that should work.

Comment: I found my problem. Actually, Sonar's plugin is deleting the `jacoco.exec` generated and is re-creating one which does not contain the dependent projects. Do you know how I can avoid the deletion of such file? I have used `-Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports` which is deprecated but seems to prevent the deletion of the file

Comment: What is the version of the SQ Java plugin you are using?

Comment: We were using 2.1 and we upgraded to 2.9.1 and the issue was resolved (We no longer needed to add `-Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports`