# SonarQube coverage does not include indirect classes

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarscanner

I have two classes classA and classB. classA calls a function which is in classB. I have a unit test for the function in classA that is calling classB's function. But this ClassB function is not covered in by SonarQube. Any help on this?

This is similar to [Sonar test coverage does not include indirect classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579555/sonar-test-coverage-does-not-include-indirect-classes)

But there is not relevent answer for dotnet.

Comment: Are you sure the method in class B is called? No if?

Comment: Yes. I am pretty sure

Comment: In release, the compiler do some optimization that mask function call (see inline function). Try in debug.